# Trying to implement k-medoids in C

Tags: c, algorithm, pointers, data-structures, linked-list

I am trying to implement an algorithm in C which splits a linked list. So what I am trying to do is, I have a linked list of all entries, I am trying to split that linked list into two separate lists based on distance of elements from a specific node.

What `shiftAndCluster` does is takes in a linked list `list`, 2 empty lists `oldFreshList` and `newList` and 2 nodes `best1` and `best2`. It first searches for these 2 nodes in `list` and pushed them into 2 empty lists respectively. Then the function iterates over each node of `list` and calculates its distance from either of the nodes and pushes it to the list containing the closer best node.

The code goes like this

```c
void shiftAndCluster(SinglyLinkedList* list, SinglyLinkedList* oldFreshList, SinglyLinkedList* newList, SinglyLinkedListNode *best1, SinglyLinkedListNode *best2)
{

    SinglyLinkedListNode *curr1 = list->front;
    SinglyLinkedList *temp = cloneFullList(list);
    SinglyLinkedListNode *prev = curr1;
    while (curr1 != NULL)
    {
        if (curr1 == best2)
        {
            break;
        } //reach till best2 in the list, so we have the prev of best2 with us
        prev = curr1;
        curr1 = curr1->next;
    }
    if (prev == curr1)
    {
        list->front = curr1->next;
        list->size--;
        SinglyLinkedList_pushFront(newList,curr1);
    }
    else
    {
        prev->next = curr1->next;
        list->size--;
        SinglyLinkedList_pushFront(newList,curr1);
    }

    curr1 = list->front;
    prev = curr1;
    
    while(curr1 != NULL)
    {
        if (curr1 == best1) {
            // break when found best1
            break;
        };
        prev = curr1;
        curr1 = curr1->next;
    }
    
    // first, middle and last
    if (prev == curr1)
    {
        list->front = curr1->next;
        list->size--;
        SinglyLinkedList_pushFront(oldFreshList,curr1);
    }
    else
    {
        
        prev->next = curr1->next;
        list->size--;
        SinglyLinkedList_pushFront(oldFreshList,curr1);
    }
    int firstSize = 1;
    int secondSize = 1;
    curr1 = list->front;    
    double dist1, dist2;
    while (curr1 != NULL && list->size)
    {
        curr1=list->front;
        SinglyLinkedList_popFront(list);

        dist1 = calculateDistance(curr1,best1);
        dist2 = calculateDistance(curr1,best2);
        if (dist1 < dist2)
        {
            SinglyLinkedList_pushFront(oldFreshList,curr1);
            firstSize++;
            if (firstSize == 10) break;
        }
        else
        {
            SinglyLinkedList_pushFront(newList,curr1);
            secondSize++;
            if (secondSize == 10) break;
        }
    }
    list->front = temp->front;
    list->size = temp -> size;
}
```

The size of `list` is 11 nodes so the algorithm stops when either of the new list reaches size 10. At the end, the old list is repopulated with it's original entries.

The struct has been defined as

```c
typedef struct SinglyLinkedListNode
{
    void *data;
    struct SinglyLinkedListNode *next;
}SinglyLinkedListNode;

typedef struct SinglyLinkedList
{
    int size;
    struct SinglyLinkedListNode *front;
}SinglyLinkedList;
```

Helper functions are:

```c
SinglyLinkedListNode* cloneList(SinglyLinkedListNode *head) {
    if(head == NULL) return NULL;
    SinglyLinkedListNode *result = (SinglyLinkedListNode *)malloc(sizeof(SinglyLinkedListNode));
    result->data = head->data;
    result->next = cloneList(head->next);
    return result;
}

SinglyLinkedList* cloneFullList(SinglyLinkedList *list) {
    if(list == NULL) return NULL;
    SinglyLinkedList *result = (SinglyLinkedList *)malloc(sizeof(SinglyLinkedList));
    result->size = list->size;
    result->front = cloneList(list->front);
    return result;
}
```

`pushFront`, `popFront` and `calculateDistance` functions are trivial and work correctly. (Can provide them if required, but I have tested them extensively, they work correctly)

The issue I am facing is that when I try to use this function in a loop, it breaks after a single iteration.

Example is

```c
//templist is a normal linked list containing 11 nodes
SinglyLinkedListNode *ppp1 = templist->front;
SinglyLinkedListNode *ppp2 = templist->front;
int ctrin = 0, ctr=0;
while (ppp1 != NULL)
{
    ctr++;
    ppp2 = templist->front;
    ctrin = 0;
    while (ppp2 != NULL)
    {
        SinglyLinkedList* tp2 = createEmptyList();
        SinglyLinkedList* np2 = createEmptyList();
        ctrin++;
        if (ppp1 == ppp2)
        {
            ppp2 = ppp2->next;
            ctrin++;
        }
        shiftAndCluster(templist, tp2, np2, ppp1, ppp2, listType, 1);
        templist = cloneFullList(list);
        printf("(%d, %d)\n", ctr, ctrin);
        ppp2 = ppp2->next;
    }
    iter++;
    ppp1 = ppp1->next;
}
```

`createEmptyList` function just creates an empty list.
The output prints `(1,2)` indicating it does check for `(1,1)` and skip it and after shifting and clustering once, it breaks down. The incoming list is fine and I think there are issues with the logic of the function. Can someone please help?

Comment: Please [edit] and post a [mcve] instead of code snippets

Answer (score 0):

May not be the only problem but when you do :

```
    prev = curr1;
    curr1 = curr1->next;
```

prev will always be different of curr1. So the test `if (prev == curr1)` if always false except if list->front is NULL